# How to display php error messages wherever I want on a html page?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, flash-message

By default a `mysqli_error` will display first thing on top of the page.

I'm trying to understand how I can echo errors wherever I want on a page.

**signup.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){


    $username = $db->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['username'])));
    $checkrow = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkrow) > 0){


        echo '<divclass="alert alert-danger">Username already exists. Please choose a different one</div>';

    }else{
//do some
}}


<html>
<body>
<div class="error_message"> Display error message here instead </div>
<form> Please sign up</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the error message in a variable, and echo it where you want.

Comment: Ah of course well thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:-

```
<?php
$error = '';//empty variable
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    $username = $db->real_escape_string(trim(strip_tags($_POST['username'])));
    $checkrow = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($checkrow) > 0){
       $error = 'Username already exists. Please choose a different one'; // assign error
    }else{
      //do some
    }
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php if(!empty($error)){?>
    <div class="error_message"><?php echo $error; // echo errors?></div>
<?php } ?>
<form> Please sign up</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:- try to read about `prepared statements` and use them to prevent from `SQL Injection`.Thanks